# What do the `%%` (two percentage) characters mean in ASP.NET Razor MVC renderer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, renderer

What do these `%%` (two percentage characters) means in ASP.NET Razor MVC renderer?

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = %%Index%%;
}
```

When I create a new View, using the Add>View menu.
with These configuration:

[image]

i got the fallowing code:

```
@model IEnumerable<CadeMeuMedico.Models.Medico>
@{
ViewBag.Title = %%Index%%;
}
<h2>Index</h2>
<p>
@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.IDMedico)
</th>
<th>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CRM)
</th>
<th>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
</th>
<th>
@Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
</th>
<th>
</th>
</tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IDMedico)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CRM)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
</td>
<td>
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
</td>

<td>
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit",
new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details",
new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) |
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete",
new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })
</td>
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Comment: Nothing.  %% has no meaning in Razor.  Whatever that is, it has nothing to do with Razor.  It looks like some kind of pre-processor token.

Comment: I edited the question and added how this code appears

Comment: @bwyn, its not a syntax error, it was generated by MVC3 Razor new view wizard